# Generate many to many list of dictionary relation from python data frame

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, dictionary

```
import pandas as pd
import os

list_of_dict2 = [[{'1580674': ['HA-567034786', 'AB-1018724']}], [{'1554970': ['AB-6348403', 'HA-7298656']}, {'1554970': ['AB-2060953', 'HA-990228']}, {'1554970': ['HA-7287204', 'AB-1092380','GR-33333']}]]

list_of_dict = []
for i in list_of_dict2:
   for j in i:
     list_of_dict.append(list(j.values())[0])

df = pd.DataFrame(list_of_dict)
print(df)
```

**My Current dataframe result**

```
              0           1         2
0  HA-567034786  AB-1018724      None
1    AB-6348403  HA-7298656      None
2    AB-2060953   HA-990228      None
3    HA-7287204  AB-1092380  GR-33333
```

using the list of a dictionary I can generate the data frame with my below code. But my problem is I am having some
problem to make it **many to many list of dictionary**. Let me explain what I want to achieve.

For example, for every row of data frame, I want to make it many to many dictionaries with multiple values on the list. Say, with the last **index 3** I want to make it like below

**Expected Output:(for 2nd index)**

```
{ 

    "AB-2060953" : ['HA-990228'],
    "HA-990228" : ['AB-2060953']

}
```

**Expected Output:(for 3rd index)**

```
{ 

"HA-7287204" : ['AB-1092380','GR-33333'],
"AB-1092380" : ['HA-7287204','GR-33333'],
"GR-33333" : ['AB-1092380','HA-7287204']
}
```

Comment: In your final expected output, why is it `"GR-33333" : ['AB-1092380','GR-33333']` and not `"GR-33333" : ['AB-1092380','HA-7287204']`

Comment: thanks mate, that was a typo :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach could be the following:

```
def make_dict(row):
    s = set(row[~row.isna()])
    return {x: list(s - {x}) for x in s}

df.apply(make_dict, axis=1)

# Output:
0    {'AB-1018724': ['HA-567034786'], 'HA-567034786': ['AB-1018724']}
1    {'AB-6348403': ['HA-7298656'], 'HA-7298656': ['AB-6348403']}
2    {'HA-990228': ['AB-2060953'], 'AB-2060953': ['HA-990228']}
3    {'GR-33333': ['AB-1092380', 'HA-7287204'], 'AB-1092380': ['GR-33333', 'HA-7287204'], 'HA-7287204': ['GR-33333', 'AB-1092380']}
dtype: object
```

Or, without assuming uniqueness and dealing with sets,

```
df.apply(lambda row: {x: [y for y in row if y and x != y] for x in row if x}, axis=1)
```